# Mad Libs Drop-down List Faliure

Tags: javascript, html, debugging

When I was making a Mad Libs game, I went to a part that was he/she. But then the name was user-generated, so I can't choose either one. So, I did this:

```js
var libButton = document.getElementById("lib-button");
var storyDiv = document.getElementById("story");
var teacher = document.getElementById("teacher");
var person = document.getElementById("person");
var gender = document.getElementById("gender").value;
var libIt = function() {
    if (gender === "xxx") {
        heShe = "He/she";
    }
    else if (gender === "male") {
        heShe = "He";
    }
    else if (gender === "female") {
        heShe = "She";
    }
    
    // The story!
    storyDiv.innerHTML = "Your story: At the beginning, " + person.value + " hated graphs. " + heShe + " just didn't get the hang of it. Then, " + teacher.value + " told " + person.value + " about the uses of graphs. " + person.value + " started to see how graphs are useful, therefore linking the outside life to graphs. Now, " + person.value + " knew why they are learning graphs, and started to get the hang of it. The end.";
};
libButton.addEventListener('click', libIt);
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>Teacher's Name: <input type="text" id="teacher"></li>
    <li>Someone's Name: <input type="text" id="person"></li>
    <li>
        <label>Gender of that person
            <select id="gender">
                <option value = "xxx">---</option>
                <option value = "male">Male</option>
                <option value = "female">Female</option>
            </select>
        </label>
    </li>
</ul>
<button id="lib-button">Lib it!</button>
```

But then, for some reason, in cloud9, when it gets to the he/she part,it always shows `heShe`, even when the drop-down list is at "Male" or "Female".
I want it to be if the drop-down menu is at "Male", then it says `He`, and when it's at "Female", It says `She`, and when it's at "---", then it says `He/she`. Why doesn't that happen?

Comment: Try to better explain what is your desired outcome and, exactly, what is going wrong. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of your `getElementById` code is outside of `libIt()` so it is grabbing all the values of the form when the page loads, essentially ignoring your choices. For #story and #lib-button it doesn't matter, but #teacher, #gender, and #person need their values fetched at the top of the function, so you get the updated values at the time you clicked the button.